# is there a way to load extensions on ROOM or a way to use math functions?

Tags: android, android-room

Room is based on SQLITE, in the documentation is possible to load extensions, even on DB Browser for SQLite theres a math extension and after loaded the query that i need works fine, i tried to replicate this on Android using Kotlin like this

database.query(SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT load_extension('$Path2Ext')"))
but this give me an exception "no such function load_extension"

i need to use math functions acos, cos, radians ...

theres a way to do this? i will appreciated any help

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is part of Android and compiled with it ever since Android was created.
Adding extensions to SQLite is very powerful and can lead misuse of the DB.
That is why SQLite had is turned off by default and Android disabled it altogether.

If you search the [Android source code](http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/external/sqlite/dist/shell.c#3503) you'll code across `SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION` that is defined by default and disables the use of extensions.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but  answer is incomplete, in fact I know that the use of extensions is not loaded by default, so my question is if there is any way to change that parameter, thanks anyway

Comment: Well. The answer is no, you can't load extensions into SQLite on Android as this ability is not even compiled into the OS. I hope this is clearer.